# What is wrong with my code? I get a "Bus Error"

Tags: c, sigbus

I'm trying to read a file containing raw audio and encode it using [FLAC](http://flac.sourceforge.net/). When I run the program, I get a "Bus Error". What could be wrong?
I'm compiling on OS X 10.6.8 using the following line:

`gcc nsFlacEncoder.c -I/opt/local/include -lflac -m32 -o flac_enc`

```
#include "FLAC/stream_encoder.h"
#define READSIZE 40000
char buffer[READSIZE];
FLAC__int32 pcm[READSIZE/2];

FLAC__StreamEncoderWriteStatus write_callback(const FLAC__StreamEncoder *encoder, const  FLAC__byte buffer[], size_t bytes, unsigned samples, unsigned current_frame, void *client_data)
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("rec.flac","rw");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int rawToFlac()
{
    FLAC__bool ok = true;
    FLAC__StreamEncoder *encoder = 0;
    FLAC__StreamEncoderInitStatus init_status;
    unsigned sample_rate = 16000;
    unsigned channels = 1;
    unsigned bps = 16;

    if((encoder=FLAC__stream_encoder_new()) == NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        return 1;
    }

    ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_verify(encoder, true);
    ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_compression_level(encoder, 5);
    ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_channels(encoder, channels);
    ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_bits_per_sample(encoder, bps);
    ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_sample_rate(encoder, sample_rate);
    ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_total_samples_estimate(encoder, READSIZE);

    if(ok){
        init_status = FLAC__stream_encoder_init_stream(encoder, &write_callback, NULL, NULL, NULL, /*client_data=*/NULL);
        if(init_status != FLAC__STREAM_ENCODER_INIT_STATUS_OK){
            printf("Encoder not initiated");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if(ok){
        while(ok)
        {       
            /* convert the packed little-endian 16-bit PCM samples from WAVE into an interleaved FLAC__int32 buffer for libFLAC */
            size_t i;
            for(i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
                /* inefficient but simple and works on big- or little-endian machines */
                pcm[i] = (FLAC__int32)(((FLAC__int16)(FLAC__int8)buffer[2*i+1] << 8) | (FLAC__int16)buffer[2*i]);
            }
            /* feed samples to encoder */
            ok = FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved(encoder, pcm, 20000);
        }
    }

    ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_finish(encoder);
    printf("Finished.");

    FLAC__stream_encoder_delete(encoder);   
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("recording","rb");
    fread(buffer,2, 20000, file);
    rawToFlac();
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Running `gdb flac_enc` gives me this:

```
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/bitmath.o" - no debug information available for "bitmath.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/bitreader.o" - no debug information available for "bitreader.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/bitwriter.o" - no debug information available for "bitwriter.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/cpu.o" - no debug information available for "cpu.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/crc.o" - no debug information available for "crc.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/fixed.o" - no debug information available for "fixed.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/format.o" - no debug information available for "format.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/lpc.o" - no debug information available for "lpc.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/md5.o" - no debug information available for "md5.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/memory.o" - no debug information available for "memory.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/metadata_iterators.o" - no debug information available for "metadata_iterators.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/metadata_object.o" - no debug information available for "metadata_object.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/stream_decoder.o" - no debug information available for "stream_decoder.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/stream_encoder.o" - no debug information available for "stream_encoder.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/stream_encoder_framing.o" - no debug information available for "stream_encoder_framing.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/window.o" - no debug information available for "window.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/ogg_decoder_aspect.o" - no debug information available for "ogg_decoder_aspect.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/ogg_encoder_aspect.o" - no debug information available for "ogg_encoder_aspect.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/ogg_helper.o" - no debug information available for "ogg_helper.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/Users/benski/Desktop/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/.libs/ogg_mapping.o" - no debug information available for "ogg_mapping.c".
```

This is strange since there is no user "benski" on my system. But I'm sure the FLAC libraries are installed properly as the [example programs](http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flac/flac/examples/c/encode/file/main.c?view=markup) work perfectly.

Comment: There's something wrong with your bus.

Comment: the error is probably in this line : 'ok = FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved(encoder, pcm, 20000);' I can't seem to tell for sure though since all i get is "Bus Error"

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I tried to comment the code block by block. The error IS in the block containing `FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved`. Do you see any obvious errors?

Comment: No, but I don't know that library. Who's giving you the error? It doesn't seem to come from your own code, so you aren't doing enough error checking, I'd say. Does the error disappear if you comment out that one line?

Comment: Are you working on MacOS X with a PowerPC machine?  The library was compiled by a user 'benski', but you don't have the source code.  That is only a warning; it means you won't be able to step through the library code and see the source lines.  That probably won't matter, unless the SIGBUS is occurring in a library function.

Comment: Are you sure your source data is interleaved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()`, you don't check that the file was opened successfully.  The trouble might be that you are using a null pointer in the `fread()` operation.  Similarly, in the `write_callback()` function, your code shows an assumption of invincibility.  (Also, if your callback is called more than once, the second call overwrites the data produced by the first call.  That, however, is a different problem.)

You don't check how many 2-byte units were read by the `fread()`.  Nor do you check how much data is written by `fwrite()` - was it successful?

You should be able to use `gdb` or a similar debugger to see where the fault occurs.

You might be able to use `valgrind` to spot the problem too.

You don't need both the `if` and the `while` in:

```
if (ok)
{
    while (ok)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The loop alone is sufficient; it will be executed zero times if `ok` is false on the first cycle.  If there was a statement after the `while` loop and before the end of the `if` then both would be necessary.

In general, a SIGBUS (bus error) occurs on RISC chips when you try to access a data object that is misaligned.  It is not clear which line could be causing that trouble in this code.  Despite the comment about 'null pointer' earlier, that more usually ends up with a SIGSEGV (segmentation violation) than a SIGBUS.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the core file by saying

```
gdb <executable name> <corefile name>
```

and then say "where" to see the traceback.  This will help you see what's failing (but as @JohnathanLeffler noted, you have a couple of bugs that can be spotted by inspection).

Answer (score 0):

Do let know more details while you expect some pointers to solve your problem, like - which platform, compiler, compiler options(whether any optimization was turned on etc..).

AFAIK a 'BUS ERROR' is thrown up if some memory read or write operation is done at a unaligned memory address. But haven't seen a bus error recently since modern systems(compilers, platforms) have removed any hard and fast need on data to be aligned to specific boundaries, unless it is a specialized hardware architecture the code is being developed for.

Now as to this particular problem you have -

(I assume it is under Linux), so Build the code with -g switch for gcc.

Then try using gdb [your executable]. This should tell which function/code line the code exits after the error. Review the code from that function/line/before and after it!

My guess(wild guess) would be where you write/read the samples to pcm[i] because it seems to be a user defined data of type FLAC__int32. But hey this could be far off, until you debug yourself. Goodluck!

Comment: Bus error doesn't occur on Intel machines very often (if at all), but does on RISC chips like SPARC or PPC.  The misaligned access on Intel simply slows the machine down.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Sure. Intel architectures would allow a unaligned data access but at cost of extra cycles consumed in accessing that address and then packing the final data bytes together. But the OP has not mentioned anything so to get him started to debug this, I mentioned about alignment. Moreover he has not mentioned the full code(i.e. his data type declarations and buffers used ).

Comment: Do SSE instructions require alignment?  I wouldn't be surprised if FLAC uses SSE to speed up its implementation.